# How to split a dictionary into a list of multiple dictionaries, all of size N in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, slice

Suppose I have a simple Python dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'location1': [1], 'location2': [1], 'location3': [1], 'location4': [1], 'location5': [1]}
```

My goal is to split this dictionary into a list of dictionaries, that are all of specific size N, except for the size of the last dictionary, which may be smaller than N if there are not enough elements in the dictionary. So N = 2 would yield:

```
[{'location1': [1], 'location2': [1]}, {'location3': [1], 'location4': [1]}, {'location5': [1]}]
```

While N = 3 would yield:

```
[{'location1': [1], 'location2': [1], 'location3': [1]}, {'location4': [1]}, 'location5': [1]}]
```

I have tried but can not find a way to do this. Note that the locations in each of the slices/batches does not matter to me, as long as they are equally distributed among slices.

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
n = 2 # the desired # of parts
items = list(d.items())
y = [dict(items[x:x+n+1]) for x in range(0, len(d), n+1)]
```

Comment: Doesn't slicing work on `d.items()` directly without converting to a list?

Comment: @MarkRansom ikr? but for some reason it didn't work for me, so I just went with this..

Comment: also need to check the order. Since dict are not ordered and might be need a loop with sorted keys or to use OrderedDict

Comment: That's interesting, I just tried it for myself and it didn't work, as you said.

Comment: @BeliaevMaksim the question makes it sound like order doesn't matter.

Comment: @BeliaevMaksim since dicts are unordered OP has to decide if he wants to order they keys alphabetically or not (or a different type of sorting)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Originally, I also tried slicing like this on d.items(), but this did not work as expected.